# Pentaho aggregate tables, cron jobs and correct schema

Tags: mysql, database, aggregate, pentaho, pentaho-ctools

I have been working in pentaho, i had to fetch complex values being calculated on run time, multiplications etc to generate aggregate values, so i did that using Pentaho Data Integration, now few of the queries are very slow, due to the complexity of the calculations being performed on a big data set.

I came to a solution that i will generate aggregate values and will save them in a table and then going to query that aggregate table. but issue is everyday transactions against new and old entries in the database. so if someone in the admin side make changes to the values i will not have updated aggregates in new table.

How can i cope up with this situation? what is the best way to do it in pentaho? I am totally confused here.

Comment: So, you want to schedule nightly reloads using the PDI?

Comment: Yes but am not sure about it. As data gets updated in the day time for the previous days enteries.